# connecting an iOS app to adhoc wifi network

Tags: ios, sockets, wifi

I have an adhoc wifi network setup via a WiFly module. I was wondering how I could connecting an iOS device to this network. Right now I am using the CFStream api. I found a tutorial which used this:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", 80, &readStream, &writeStream);
```

To connect to a server. However I don't want to have a server I just want to communicate with my WiFly module to the iOS device via a server. Just direct communication over the adhoc network. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You might find this question informative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057053/does-iphone-support-wifi-ad-hoc-mode

Comment: but, do you know how to initialize this connection from the iOS app?

Comment: Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215165/connecting-an-ios-app-to-wifly-module/16066842#16066842